# Building a media center and a remote torrent downloader

Tags: pi-3, networking

My idea is to have the RB connected via HDMI to a TV and to internet via Ethernet. I want to have a media center to play any media to the TV using Kodi (for example) but i also want to download torrents to a hard drive plugged into the pi.
Can i use rtorrent (which is a Kodi's addon) to download torrents from my computer to the pi?
I want some sort of automatically downloading torrent machine but the problem I have is that i don't really know how to send the torrent files to the pi. Maybe using a DNLA or rtorrent?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best served looking at htpcguides.com. There is a lot in this space, with separate apps for movies (CouchPotato, Watcher, Radarr), shows (SickGear, Sonarr), comics (Mylar), books (LazyLibrarian), music (Headphones), and other media; then there are dozens (literally!) of torrenting apps and NZB apps (the usenet equivalent of torrenting, without the P2P aspect. Pay attention to the guides on VPN'ing, as this could save you stress should you get in a situation....

Edit: and if those apps are too stringent for your purposes, check out Flexget....